# Nuget packaging: Possible to target early frameworks only?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have some code that works in dotnet 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 but not in 4.0 and greater. Is there a mechanism within Nuget to target these earlier frameworks only?

Comment: You can provide different assemblies for particular target frameworks in the NuGet package's lib folder. However if you have say a net40 folder, and no later versions, then it is considered compatible will all later versions. You could use an empty folder containing _._ to make it a no-op for later frameworks. Is there a reason why you cannot supply an assembly for later frameworks or why it is only compatible with older versions?

Comment: @matt-ward This solution worked thanks. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer.